# Add Section Name to SEOmatic Title Field

Tags: craft3, plugin-seomatic

I have an index page for a Section which lists out the entries.

As this index template doesn't have a title field associated with it how do I get the Section name in the SEOmatic's SEO Title Source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do this via Twig as discussed here: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#twig-templating

...but you can also just make an Single for your Index page (this is what I usually do) and all of this will "just work" including the SEO sidebar previews in the CP.